# How to allow selection for user in a map?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app that, when the user taps a map, it search for towns within 5 km of the tapped point. In the Android version, a ListView is displayed to allow the user select the town, in case there is more than one town in a 5 km radius.

There is no ListView in iOS. I thought to present an UIAlertView and put a picker there, to allow the user selection, BUT, according to Apple, you can not do that.

My question is, is there a way I can achieve that goal without being marked as "uncool" by Apple when I submit my app, and have it rejected?

Thank you.

Comment: `UITableView` should be the iOS equivalent of Android `ListView`.

Comment: You can't (you actually CAN, but you shouldn't, according to Apple's Human Guidelines) put a UITableView inside an AlertView.

Comment: In the "Android" version, you didn't said that you put a ListView into a "alertView". You should find a nice design to show your UITableView. Either coming from the bottom, etc.

Comment: In the Android version the ListView is presented directly over the map, but that cannot be made in iOS. That's why I thought in using an UIAlertView.